# How do I fix SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet after Project clean?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am working on a dynamic web project using JSP and multiple servlets with tomcat Apache and Eclipse.

I was having multiple problems with Eclipse today and I ran a clean on the project to try to fix some of the issues that I was having and ever since, I'm getting the following error every time a servlet is called.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [RegisterServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ogi.controller.RegisterServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

This project was working completely fine on localhost before the clean and I have all of the servlets defined in my web.xml file. CATALINA has an environmental variable and I already have the Jar files in my project.

I'm not sure why these errors are occurring and would appreciate some direction on how to attempt to fix this.